# How to make my pylab.poly1d(fit) pass through zero?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

My code bellow produces a polyfit of the points in my graph, but I want this fit to always pass through zero, how do I do this?

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

y=(abs((UX2-UY2)+(2*UXY)))
a=np.mean(y)
y=y-a
x=(abs((X2-Y2)+(2*XY)))
b=np.mean(x)
x=x-b
ax=pl.subplot(1,4,4) #plot XY
fit=pl.polyfit(x,y,1)
slope4, fit_fn=pl.poly1d(fit)
print slope4
fit_fn=pl.poly1d(fit)
x_min=-2
x_max=5
n=10000
x_fit = pl.linspace(x_min, x_max, n) 
y_fit = fit_fn(x_fit)
q=z=[-2,5]
scat=pl.plot(x,y, 'o', x_fit,y_fit, '-r', z, q, 'g' )
```

Comment: It looks like it is doing a least squares fit, so pinning it to a specific point is hard.  I would roll your own least-squares fitter (you can do it with just some matrix math) and omit the constant term.

Comment: im now trying to use numpy.linalg.lstsq(a, b, rcond=0) to see if this works

Comment: That is probably better than rolling your own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you fit an n-degree polynomial `p(x) = a0 + a1*x + a2*x**2 + ... + an*x**n` to a set of data points `(x0, y0), (x1, y1), ..., (xm, y_m)`, a call to `np.lstsq` is made with a coefficient matrix that looks like:

```
[1 x0 x0**2 ... x0**n]
[1 x1 x1**2 ... x1**n]
...               
[1 xm xm**2 ... xm**n]
```

If you remove the `j`-th column from that matrix, you are effectively setting that coefficient in the polynomial to 0. So to get rid of the `a0`  coefficient you could do the following:

```
def fit_poly_through_origin(x, y, n=1):
    a = x[:, np.newaxis] ** np.arange(1, n+1)
    coeff = np.linalg.lstsq(a, y)[0]
    return np.concatenate(([0], coeff))

n = 1000
x = np.random.rand(n)
y = 1 + 3*x - 4*x**2 + np.random.rand(n)*0.25

c0 = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit(x, y, 2)
c1 = fit_poly_through_origin(x, y, 2)

p0 = np.polynomial.Polynomial(c0)
p1 = np.polynomial.Polynomial(c1)

plt.plot(x, y, 'kx')
xx = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
plt.plot(xx, p0(xx), 'r-', )
plt.plot(xx, p1(xx), 'b-', )
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

As was mentioned, you can't really do it explicitly with `polyfit` (but you can write your own function).

However, if you want to still use `polyfit()` you can try this math hack: add a point at zero, and then use the `w` flag (weights) in `polyfit()` to give it a high weight while all other points get a low weight. This will have the effect of forcing the polynomial to pass at zero or very close.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I don't particularly like this answer when there is an exact solution available. In real-life cases, how big is a weight? If it's too big you might wind up with rounding errors for the rest of the points, if it's too small it might work for some problems but not others (the worst kind of bug!).

Comment: @Hooked that's why it is a hack, in case OP wants to keep using `polyfit` (which he may or may not). I explicitly wrote this in my nswer. BTW the worst kind of bug is a bug that you don't know about.